# File picker hangs or is slow with USB drive attached

Tags: finder, hard-drive, usb, external-disk

I have a M1 MacBook Pro, 2021, with Sonoma 14. I attached a Seagate 16TB External USB 3.1 drive, to use as my time machine and an archive of video projects.

https://www.seagate.com/support/external-hard-drives/desktop-hard-drives/expansion-desktop/

I have an APFS container with 2 volumes:

- Time Machine
- Expansion

Drives mount fine, I can move files around, everything's grand.

Except, often when a file picker is spawned (such as saving a PDF from my web browser), the file picker won't navigate my file structure.  Whatever directory it is in is the ONLY directory I can select. I can‘t select folders, I can‘t move up in the tree, I can‘t select a Favorite. The file picker is frozen; all I can do is exit the file picker.

I noticed recently that when the file picker appears, my external drive starts seeking. So, as an experiment, the next time my file picker froze, I unmounted the Expansion drive and Time Machine, re-opened the file picker, and it worked correctly.

I have consistently been able to "unfreeze" my file picker by unmounting the expansion drive. Which is very irritating, especially as it's my Time Machine. The drive doesn't have a power switch, so the only way I know to remount it is to unplug the USB cable and plug it back in again, which is difficult due to the drive's placement.

I would really love to know if (1) this is a common occurrence and (2) if there's a way to fix this.

Comment: I don’t have this drive, but are you using the software supplied by Seagate, and if you are, is it the latest version available from the Seagate website?

Comment: @IconDaemon , the software listed is Windows and Linux software, backup software and a SMART tool.  No Mac tools.  And I checked my serial number, the drive doesn't have firmware updates necessary.  I'm just using Apple tools at this time.

Comment: As for remounting the drive, it should show up in Disk Utility as unmounted, and you can easily remount with a mouse-click. There should be no need to physically unplug/replug to remount. Furthermore, should the drive mechanism suffer catastrophic problems rendering it useless, you’ve lost both the Time  Machine _and_ the Expansion volumes in one fell swoop. Having suffered data loss by having a disk partitioned into separate TM and storage volumes, I have separate TM drives and external storage drives.